# REGEX string extraction between underscore and file extension

Tags: regex

I have a series of string like the following one:

*abc_8g_1980_312.tif*

from which I would like to extract the string '312' i.e. everything between the 3rd underscore and the file extension'.tif' string.

I'm trying using this website https://regex101.com/
inserting this regular expression: `(\d{3})(\.tif$)`

but I'm not getting what I would like to have.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Would the 3rd underscore also always be the *last* underscore? Would you for example always be looking for exactly three digits, or can this be any type of characters other than an underscore? Would you always need to make sure the extension is "tif"?

Comment: @JvdV yes, the 3rd underscore will always be the last one and I'm always looking for those last three digits

Comment: @sylar_80, right. I guess by question boils down to if you need to validate your string further? Do you need to know it has three underscores? Do you need to make sure there are just three digits after the last underscore? Does it has to always be the "tif" file extension?

Comment: @JvdV it is a naming convention of a series of files. It is supposed to not change in the future

Comment: Maybe `_(\d{3})\.tif$` would work for you, or use lookarounds as per the given answers below.

Comment: @sylar_80 Did any of the answers work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last 3 digits after an underscore with extension `.tif` you can also use lookarounds asserting `_` to the left, and `.tif` to the right at the end of the string.

```
(?<=_)\d{3}(?=\.tif$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJPiWE/1)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you want to capture would always be the *last* underscore-separated term in your file name, you could use:

```regex
(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.)
```

### Demo